# how to programatically run a website profiling and get total javascript execution time ( scripting in summary of google chrome profiler )

Tags: performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, profiling, performance-testing

I am trying to run some profiling on hourly basis for an application.

I need the total scripting duration value ( scripting in summary of google chrome profiler ). How to get this value by code ( and possible run an automated job )

[image: google chrome profiler preview]